# socket closing if user user exists

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm trying to create a server/client application for a school project.

I have a server on a given port, multiple users connected, and each user has their own username.

Now I want to check if a user that tries to connect is using a valid username.  For example if a user with username A is already connected a new user that want to connect cannot use the username A.

If this happens the server responds to the new client with an error code.

This is the code for this part:

```
   private void Receive()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[64];
            socket.Receive(buffer);
            string received = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);
            if (received.IndexOf("!error") != -1)
            {
                string[] mySplit = received.Split(':');
                string errorCode = mySplit[1].Trim((char)0);
                if (errorCode == "user exists")
                {
                    richTextBox1.AppendText("Your connection was refused by server, because there's already another user connected with the username you choose");
                    socket.Disconnect(true);

                    connectBtn.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When I try to do this the program crashs and visual studio says that there's an invalid
cross-thread operation on `richTextBox1`.

Comment: "responds to the new client with an error code": not an adequate problem description. Always give the *actual* error code, by cut & paste, preferably with an indication of which line caused it.

Answer (score 4):

You can only access UI elements from the UI thread.  If you try to access them from a background thread you'll get this exception.  This code needs to run in a background thread so that you don't block the UI thread forever and freeze your application.

There are several ways to marshal back to the UI thread, part of which depends on how you decided to start a background thread in the first place.  (If you're using a `BackgroundWorker, Tasks,`await`, etc. there are built in ways of doing this.)

One general purpose option option is to just use `Invoke`:

```
if (errorCode == "user exists")
{
    this.Invoke(new Action(()=> { DisplayError(); } ));
}
```

`DisplayError` can then contain all of your UI code for this situation.  Note that in general it's best to separate out UI code from business logic.  Embedding UI code all throughout your application is undesirable.

Comment: Do you know how i can "close" and reuse the socket?

Comment: @corvallo You should ask a new question if you have a separate problem you need to solve with this code.

Comment: @corvallo You can't reuse sockets. Just close it and start again with a new one.